# What is the equivalent of else do nothing using the conditional operator?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, inline

I want to know what is the equivalent of this if statement:

```
if (condition) {
        // do something
    }else{
        // do nothing

    }
```

Using the conditional operator:

```
(condition) ? // [do nothing] : {do nothing} "
```

Comment: why checking the condition if you want to 'do nothing' in either branch?

Comment: why not just `if (condition) do something;` ?

Comment: it just popped in my head, what DO NOTHING looks like in this kind of statement.
my Solution was to create a (void) doNothing{} that does nothing.

Comment: these are asked in interviews :)

Comment: @DrummerB: I think leaving space for `else`, for future :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to "do nothing" using the conditional operator. You always have to have valid expressions on both sides, although both expressions can be casted to `void`.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the dis-advantage of ternary operator ( ?: ).

It needs expressions in all the three places. You cant skip any of them.

You can do some tweak on it, however its True-part and / or False-part can be assigned to the same as :

```
int big=100;
big= (10 > 100) ? 0 : big;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!condition) {
        // do something
    }else{
        // do nothing

    }
```

Take a look at the !before contition now :-)

The ! before the condition just switches the "if", to "if not"...

Is that what you have been searching for?

Answer (score 0):

```
originalValue = (condition) ? newValue : originalValue
```

The compiler should then remove the unnecessary assign of *originalValue* to itself.

GCC had an extension to do give you something more to what you where looking for, something like

```
originalValue = condition ?: newValue;
```

So it may be available in clang also. You would have to ! the condition though.

Answer (score 0):

In normal code the answer is there is no equivalent - all sub expressions of an expression must have a value, but...

**the following is not a recommendation**

Something along the lines of the following should work in the general case:

```
condition ? ( (^{ do something })(), 0 ) : 0;
```

That is for the general case. If *do something* is a single, non-compound, statement; such as a method call; then the block can be dropped to give:

```
condition ? (do something, 0) : 0;
```

**Again this is NOT recommended in real code!**

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
someBool ? [self someFunction] : (^{})(); //empty block
```

Comment: Nice try, but the compiler should reject that - if the method is non-void then the two branches have non-matching types, and if the method is void you can't have a void in an expression as it is not a value...

Comment: the OP isn't assigning the results to anything so it will work in this case. even if OP was going to assign it, then you could probably just set the return type of the block to the same as the function. edit: just tested, if you make the block `(^{return 1;})()` then it works if you are assigning to an int.

Comment: The compiler should reject if the two branches have different types; but I was wrong, the branches can have void type - a little illogical but that is C! So provided you either omit the return, if the first branch is void, or return a value of compatible type, then it is legal; otherwise not. However we come back to the "compiler *should* reject", brief testing in Xcode 4.6 shows the compiler may be lax - in violation of the spec (ISO C). The comma operator can be used to make it legal - see my earlier answer - for a conforming compiler. But this is all just fun, don't write code like this!